# Can't locate a file inside the project

Tags: java, file, io, path

Okay; So I've been using Windows for quite some time, however I've recently moved over to a linux-based operating system. I've ran into numerous issues such as the File-System for Linux being case-sensative. IE: Filename.PNG will not load if you try to load Filename.png.

Anyway, That's not my problem here, and I'm kind-of confused.

Here's my problem, in cropped picture format, code and all.

[image]

I've tried varations, such as "/SpriteSheets/tileset.jpg", "assets/SpriteSheets/tileset.jpg"

However, I can't get it to work.

Comment: Isn't the filename tileset.png and not tileset.jpg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems your file name is **`tileset.png`** and not `tileset.jpg`.

Comment: Have I really been staring at this for an hour, and over-looked that? :facedesk: EDIT: Changing the code to load the .png doesn't help

Comment: I am afraid so ;-) The good thing is that it may be the solution.

Comment: System.out.println(new File("SpriteSheets/tileset.png").exists()); still returns false .-.

Comment: Try with ``System.out.println(new File("assets/SpriteSheets/tileset.png").exists());``

Comment: Voila! Strange, can you explain why sometimes the "assets" is needed, and sometimes it is not depending on how you're loading the file?

Answer (score 0):

Print your current path first with a `System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath())` and then try and see where you should point your path in the program.

EDIT: Eclipse usually points your path inside the workspace, I've had trouble with that previously. You can set the runtime path to a different directory; Go to `Run configurations`, choose your configuration, choose tab `Arguments` and set the working directory (at the bottom) to a directory of your choosing.